# Why are my radiobuttons not mutually exclusive?

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, buttongroup

I am trying to implement two radiobuttons and make them mutually exclusive.

```
    public ProvincesPanel() {
    //radiobuttons definitions.csv
    this.setName("Provinces 2");
    ButtonGroup vanillaOrMod = new ButtonGroup();
    vanillaOrMod.add(rdbDefNew);
    vanillaOrMod.add(rdbDefVan);
    rdbDefNew= new JRadioButton("new definition.csv file");
    rdbDefVan= new JRadioButton("vanilla definition.csv file");
    add(rdbDefNew);
    add(rdbDefVan);
    }
```

Now for some reason that I don't understand ,the buttons are still not exclusive?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to add your JRadioButton variables to the ButtonGroup ***before*** you've created the radio button objects themselves, and in fact it looks as if you're trying to add nulls to the ButtonGroup.

Solution: Don't do this. Create your JRadioButton objects **first**, and only **then** add them to the ButtonGroup.

Comment: Thanks! Ill accept your answer once the timer runs out :)